# Como executar um código JAVASCRIPT pelo PHP sem evento

Tags: php, javascript, javascript-eventos

Seguinte, estou tentando substituir o `alert` pelo `modal` [dessa](http://jquerymodal.com/?) lib que usa o jquery. No caso estou usando o primeiro exemplo:

```
<div id="ex1" class="modal">
  <p>Usuário ou senha incorretos.</p>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Fechar</a>
</div>

<p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>
```

Porém, no meu caso, esse href deve ser executado no controller do php. Aí que entra o meu problema. Como eu poderia acionar essa modal sem um evento (tipo click, por exemplo)? No caso ao que estou me referindo é `echo '<script> código </script>';`. Obrigado.

Comment: Por que não pode usar um evento click?

Comment: Vc quer que seja executado, abrir o modal, logo dps da execução do php?

Comment: Por que ele deve ser acionado de acordo com um resultado de uma query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a documentação **[neste link](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal)**, você pode abrir a modal manualmente apenas chamando o método `.modal()` do plugin sobre o elemento. Sendo assim não é necessário disparar um evento para isso. O `echo` seria:

```
<?php
echo "<script> $('#ex1').modal(); </script>";
?>
```

O seletor `'#ex1'` refere-se ao `id` da modal.

Exemplo sem uso do PHP, apenas para ilustrar o funcionamento:

```js
$('#ex1').modal();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
<div id="ex1" class="modal">
  <p>Usuário ou senha incorretos.</p>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Fechar</a>
</div>

<p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>
```

Lembrando que, dependendo de onde o `echo` for executado, a lib do jQuery e os elementos já devem ter sido carregados. Neste caso, para se prevenir, seria interessante executar o método após o DOM ter sido carregado:

```
<?php
echo "<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ $('#ex1').modal(); });
</script>";
?>
```